# Making CMake apply -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to everything

Tags: permissions, software-installation, cmake

I'm trying to build this app with CMake, as a non-root user. I've run:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$HOME/opt
```

but during `make install`, I get

```
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/myapp/data
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:44 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot make directory "/usr/local/share/wesnoth/data": No such
  file or directory
```

So, CMake still created the makefiles to installl *some* of the built stuff into `/usr/local/`. What do I need to do to make *everything* go under -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ?

Notes:

- It's Wesnoth 1.13.4, if you must know, but please try to answer generally rather than specifically.

Comment: Even though you do not realize it, this question needs to be addressed specifically if you want a solution.  `cmake` does not decide where files go, the configuration files you use do.

Comment: @JuliePelletier: But surely CMake has `/usr/share` or `/usr` somewhere as a default - isn't there some global override for it?